# Xcode 9 beta 6 error "Reference to 'sqlite3_value' is ambiguous"

Tags: objective-c, fmdb, ios11, xcode9beta6

I got the below compilation error in FMDB/FMDatabase.m:1404:74:

> Reference to 'sqlite3_value' is ambiguous

when I test my iOS project with xCode 9 beta 6.
It is working fine in xCode 8.3.2.

My FMDB library version is 2.4.

I have marked font in bold, where I got compilation error in following lines:

void FMDBBlockSQLiteCallBackFunction(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, **sqlite3_value** **argv); // -Wmissing-prototypes

void FMDBBlockSQLiteCallBackFunction(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, **sqlite3_value** **argv) {

Please find the following complete function code snippet in which I got error and also I have attache screenshot for the same [image: here].

```
#pragma mark Callback function

void FMDBBlockSQLiteCallBackFunction(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv); // -Wmissing-prototypes
void FMDBBlockSQLiteCallBackFunction(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv) {  
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
    void (^block)(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv) = (id)sqlite3_user_data(context);
#else
    void (^block)(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv) = (__bridge id)sqlite3_user_data(context);
#endif
    if (block) {
        block(context, argc, argv);
    }
}
```

I have tried to resolved it but can not found the solution for it.
It would be appreciate if any help I will get.

Thank you

**UPDATE:** In Xcode 9(Final release), it is working fine.

Comment: Why not update to FMDB 2.7?

Comment: I have tried  with FMDB 2.7 but it can not work with it. As it is part of my old project migration so will update once the code migration completed.

Answer (score 0):

how about 
1. Clean the project
2. Delete everything inside '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/' (the button inside the organizer window did not work for me)
3. Clean once more
4. Build project

Comment: I have updated my question as it it working fine in Xcode 9 public release.